# Dynamically Adding paper-dropdown-input inside a template dom-repeat

Tags: javascript, polymer-2.x

I'm trying to dynamically add paper-dropdown-inputs in my project. It would look something like this:

```
<dom-module id="stuff-input-list">
<template>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[stuffs]]" as="stuff_item">
  <paper-dropwdown-input  label="[[stuff_item.name]]" items='{{stuff_item.list_values}}' filter-property="name">
     <template>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[items]]" as="stuff">
                <paper-item>[[stuff.value_name]]</paper-item>
        </template>
       </template>
  </paper-dropwdown-input>
</template>

</template>


<script>

class StuffList extends Polymer.Element {
            static get is() {
                return 'stuff-input-list';
            }

            static get properties() {
                return {

                };
            }

            constructor() {
                super();
                this.stuffs = {
                  [name:'Stuff 1', list_values: [{value_name: 'Hey'}] ],
                  [name:'Stuff 2', list_values: [{value_name: 'World'}] ],
                  [name:'Stuff 3', list_values: [{value_name: '!'}] ]

                }
            }

            ready() {
                super.ready();

                Polymer.RenderStatus.afterNextRender(this, function() {

                });
            }

        }

        window.customElements.define(StuffList.is, StuffList);

</script>


</dom-module>
```

where `stuff` would be an object with an attr name and a `list_values` attr that is a list of objects like name.

Problems:

1) Currently, the sample code above has trouble rendering the list/`paper-item`. I would  need to type on the search input before the lists appears.

2) I need to put this in a dialog form. My problem right now is how to return the selected values for each repeat? I could achieve this easily if I had a `paper-dropdown-input` for each stuff. But since I need to dynamically add stuff, I need to achieve this in a dom-repeat.

Comment: May you add some example JS as well?

Comment: @evolutionxbox added them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ad 1) You need to create `properties` for all data you want to bind in your template. While you can initialise those right away, your initialisation code will be run for every class/component instance, so make sure you wrap it in a function:

```
static get properties() {
    return {
        stuffs: {
            type: Array,
            notify: true,
            value: () => [{
                name:'Stuff 1', 
                list_values: [{value_name: 'Hey'}],
                selected_value: null
            }, {
                name:'Stuff 2', 
                list_values: [{value_name: 'World'}],
                selected_value: null
            }, {
                name:'Stuff 3',
                list_values: [{value_name: '!'}],
                selected_value: null 
            }]
        }
    };
}
```

If your data happens to be fetched asynchronously, keep the property (with its `type` and `notify`) and use `this.set('stuffs', data)` to ensure correct update of your template.

ad 2) This will also be achieved using data binding. First you'll need the above `notify` property on your Array property. Second, each 'stuff'-object should have its own selection value. Using the correct data binding, modifications to your Array values (by the bound paper-dropdown-inputs) will be propagated accordingly:

```
...
<paper-dropwdown-input  label="[[stuff_item.name]]" 
    selected-item="{{stuff_item.selected_value}}" 
    items='{{stuff_item.list_values}}' filter-property="value_name">
        ...
```

Comment: Your second answer worked as expected. I'll need to try your first one though. Here's another question, how do I change the my selected value? By default it seems to be in name, but what if I want it to be id (an int) instead? Or what if I want to my selected to be an object?

Comment: @Mikebarson My guess is that you're using Juravenator/paper-dropdown-input from webcomponents.org. In that case, your selectedItem will always hold the value from the items array, no matter if that is a Number or an Object. Also, make sure the filterProperty matches any existing property of the items in your list_values. I have updated my answer's code accordingly.